# override keyword usecase + what it does

Tags: solidity, solidity-0.7.x

```
    function burn(uint tokens) override external returns (bool success) {
        balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].sub(tokens);
        _totalSupply = _totalSupply.sub(tokens);
        emit Transfer(msg.sender, address(0), tokens);
        return true;
    }
```

just wondering what overrride actually does and when to use it

Comment: Read about inheritance in [the official documentation](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.6.0/contracts.html?highlight=override#inheritance).

Comment: And more generally with regards to your questions about Solidity keywords here (like [this one](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/90104/16043)) - please search these keywords in the official documentation instead of asking others to do it for you.